# How is cosine similarity performed in this Keras word2vec implementation?

Tags: python, keras, word2vec, cosine-similarity, word-embedding

I'm following a tutorial
http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/
which uses cosine similarity for validation model but dot product (not normalized unlike cosine similarity) for training. That's really confusing but my question is about axis of dot product, for validation model it's:

```
similarity = merge([target, context], mode='cos', dot_axes=0)
```

as a result when I log the model summary for the validation model I get:

> Layer (type) Output Shape
>
> dot_1 (Dot) (300, 1, 1)

but for training model

```
dot_product = merge([target, context], mode='dot', dot_axes=1)
```

not surprisingly model summary shows a different thing

> Layer (type) Output Shape
>
> dot_2 (Dot) (None, 1, 1)

I've read 'Ouput' in the summary (who's value is usually None) shows batch size (if it's fixed for some reason) but it still doesn't make sense to me why it's 300 for the first model because I think batch size in the example is not fixed and 300 is also my embedding dimension. Clearly something's wrong the `dot_axes`, can anybody confirm? Do I just fix it by putting `dot_axes=1` instead of zero? Why is first axis 1 and not 0? Does `dot_axes=0` dot over batch size or what (makes no sense to me)?

code on github:
https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/master/keras_word2vec.py